# Sorting an array with object values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

This is an array with objects inside of it, how can I sort it so the lowest score is the first one showing in the array?

```
var theArray = [{username: "A", scores: 12}, 
                {username: "B", scores: 4}, 
                {username: "C", scores: 2}]
```

So that username: "C" would become the first one in the array.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: `theArray.sort((a, b) => a.scores - b.scores)`

Comment: [Array Sort][1]


You'll want to use array.sort.

    theArray.sort(function(obj1, obj2){ return obj1.scores - obj2.scores;});

This

  [1]: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp